# Expression to select features by comparing attribute values

Tags: qgis, select-by-attribute, expression

I'm working in QGIS and I have a point layer with two fields and I'm trying to compare the accuracy of the distances in feet. One field highlights the old calculated distances and another field highlights the new.

How do I select all the features in this point layer that have a plus or minus change of less than 50 (feet)?

Both fields are already in feet unit so I do not need any statements including conversions.

Does anyone know an expression to do this selection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Select by Expression` (CTRL+F3) you can get the desired result by writing:

```
 "NEW" >= "OLD" - 50 AND "NEW" <= "OLD" + 50
```